# How or when to add a copyright notice in published games?

Tags: legal, copyright

I've seen lot of videogame title screens show a copyright notice together with the company name. I'm about to publish my game and I am looking for possibilities or requirements on how or when to add such a copyright notice (including date or year published). Does it apply to both indie game makers and larger companies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no requirement. Copyright is automatic the moment you produce a creative work. An explicit copyright notice is optional and not required to claim a copyright later. It is just a friendly reminder of who the copyright owner is and that they care about the copyright of their work.

When you want one, you can place it anywhere you like.

When someone violates your copyright, a copyright message can serve as a proof that you are the original author. So you should try to integrate it into your game in a way that removing it requires effort.

Comment: re *Copyright is automatic*: Strictly speaking this only applies to [countries who have ratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parties_to_international_copyright_agreements) the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works), though that's almost all of them.

Comment: I see. Then, I can add the copyright notice myself straight ahead without seeking any professionals or legal advisers for help.

Comment: @Anko The countries that haven't ratified the Berne Convention won't care even if you put a copyright notice on your game. Wherever Copyright exists at all, it is automatic. The notice might make things easier if it ever comes to your copyright being contested in court, and should be correct, but you'd have to talk to a lawyer about that.